# How do I select value on the basis of another value?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to look for list of distinct acct_number that has no '0' as Status_code .
I have following records in my table:

```
Acct_number   Status_code 
 1234              0
 1234              1
 1234             -1
 2345              2
 2345              3
 2345             -1
 3456              3
 3456              0
 3456              -1
```

I want out put be like this:

```
 acct_number
  2345
```

Both 1234  and 3456  has '0' as status_code  .  2345 is the only one that does not have '0' as status_code

My query looks like this but it does not give right result:

```
 with cte as(
 select distinct acct_number,count(distinct status_code)  
 from  XXX
 where ---------
 and status_code<>'0'
 group by acct_number
 having count(distinct status_code) >1)
      select  distinct sk.acct_number, a.acct_number, sk.status_code 
      from  XXX b, cte a
      where -----
      and  b.status_code<>'0'
      and b.acct_number=a.acct_number;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use aggregation as:

```
select Acct_number
from t
group by Acct_number
having sum(case when status_code = 0 then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Or, if you have a separate table of accounts, then:

```
select a.*
from accounts a
where not exists (select 1
                  from account_status acs
                  where acs.acct_number = a.acct_number and acs.status_code = 0
                 );
```

Comment: Wow, Gordon this is incredible. At this pace you will be in top 5 SO user in a few days. Good job :D

Answer (score 1):

Just distinct is enough

`select distinct Acct_number 
   from table_name 
  where Status_code  <> '0';`

Answer (score 0):

use not exists

```
select t1.* from XXX t1
 where not exists ( select 1 from 
                   XXX t2 where t2.Acct_number=t1.Acct_number
                    and Status_code=0)
```

or you can use aggregation

```
select Acct_number
from XXX
group by Acct_number
having sum(case when Status_code = 0 then 1 else 0 end)<>1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists` clause to eliminate all accounts which have at least one record with status code=0.

```
select distinct X1.acct_number  
     from  XXX as X1
     where not exists (select 1 from XXX as X2
     where X2.status_code=0
    and x2.acct_number=x1.acct_number)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your answer would be improved by explaining how it addresses the question. See stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer